# Querying the Month part of a date in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I can query year part of a date using `String [] selectionArgs = { "2018" };`

```
String query =
  "SELECT * FROM TABLE" +
  "WHERE strftime('%Y', COLUMN_DATE) = ?" + 
  "ORDER BY strftime('%m', COLUMN_DATE) DESC;"

return db.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);
```

But I am having trouble querying the month part of the date like I did for the year part.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the date to have a specific month (without having constraints on the year or the date), you can continue to use the `strftime` function. Querying results for *October:*

```sql
WHERE strftime('%m', COLUMN_DATE) = '10'                  /* October */
```

---

If you want to query results for a *specific* month-year, you can combine both of them like this:

```sql
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', COLUMN_DATE) = '2011-05'          /* May, 2011 */
```

Comment: I was using single string value for the month like this `"5"` instead of `"05"`